# How do I insert spaces in a string, including around the space in the string?

Tags: javascript

Using code I found researching how to insert spaces between the characters of a string ([here](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/150486-js-insert-character-every-2nd-character-string.html)), I modified the result, but this doesn't insert additional spaces around the space between 'hello' and 'world' — would you please let me know what I'm missing? Also, what does L%2 do? Thanks! It's important that the result output to the browser.

```
var s = 'hello world';

var L = s.length;

L = (L%2) ? ' ' + s.charAt(L-1) : '';  
// what does L%2 do?

var M = s.match(/(.{1})/g) ;

if (M) s = M.join(' ') ;

document.write(s);
```

Comment: *"but this doesn't insert additional spaces around the space"* It does, but HTML collapses consecutive spaces. Do a `console.log` instead.

Comment: `L%2` is `L modulo 2` and will be `0` if `L` can be divided by `2` and has a `0` rest [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). To multiple spaces try using `&nbsp;` instead of ` `.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix. Yes, in console.log I see the extra space. How can I have the extra spaces display in HTML?

Comment: the % sign is the modulo. "the rest of the division". so, 10%2 = 0, 11%2 = 1. In your case it evaluates to true (1) if L is an odd number, and to false (0) if L is an even number.

Comment: wrap it in <pre> tag.

Comment: There are a couple of ways, as already suggested: Put the output inside `<pre>` tag or use non-collapsing spaces, such as `&nbsp;` or `&emsp;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the question in the thread you've linked to is different from yours, and that code doesn't make much sense in your case. To insert a space (or whatever) between characters in a string, you simply use

```
 string.split("").join(whatever)
```

Example:

```js
s = "hello world";
f = s.split("").join("&nbsp;");
document.write(f)
```

If your ultimate goal is to increase spacing between characters, a much simpler (and more correct) way is to use css:

```html
<span style="letter-spacing: 0.5em">hello world</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, @georg. You answer is much simpler, and regarding the usage of CSS I agree and it is what I would do. The question was part of a job code test that I couldn't answer, so I set about learning it afterwards. I particularly love the simplicity of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

> ...but this doesn't insert additional spaces around the space...

It does, but HTML collapses consecutive spaces, so the additional spaces are not *visibile*. Do a `console.log` instead.

> what does L%2 do?

See [Understanding the modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18729180/218196) and [Find if variable is divisible by 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2821006/218196).

Here it is used to check whether `L`, the length of the string, is even or odd. However, since you are not using `L`, it doesn't seem to be of any relevance.

---

In order to make the spaces visible in HTML you can either

- Put the output inside a `<pre>` element. This element *pre*serves spaces.
- Insert a non-collapsing space instead, such as `&nbsp;` or `&emsp;`.

Comment: Thank you, Felix.  The explanation of L%2 is helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get spaces to appear on the page where spaces already exist use:

```
  &nbsp;
```

(short for non-breaking space) instead.

As for:

```
 L%2
```

That's short for "give me the remainder", in common circles called "modulo" or just "mod"

So 2%2 (or if L is even) remainder would equal 0, or evaluated as false, while 3%2 (or if L is odd) would always equal 1 and evaluated as true. It's a common conditional for saying "do this to every other operation I'm iterating/looping over".

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&nbsp;` instead of a space.